# Error on add-migration - Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

We tried this article to implement database based tenant provider - https://www.codingame.com/playgrounds/5440/multi-tenant-asp-net-core-2---implementing-database-based-tenant-provider
... and it has 2 database context ApplicationDbContext and MultiTenantDbContext.

We managed to do `add-migration init and update-database` for the ApplicationDbContext BUT we could **NOT** do the 2nd one for MultiTenantDbContext ... and it keeps saying issue on Object reference not set to an instance of an object which is related on `var host = accessor.HttpContext.Request.Host.Value; on /Models/Tenant.cs below.

Also my 2nd questions, I don't understand why this DatabaseTenantProvider class get executed in add-migration init on the MultiTenantDbContext ?!?!

Any ideas?

Here's the code:

**/Models/Tenant.cs:**

```
using AthlosifyCore.Data;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace AthlosifyCore.Models
{
    public class Tenant
    {
        [Key]
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string HostName { get; set; }
    }

    public interface ITenantProvider
    {
        Guid GetTenantId();
    }

    public class DatabaseTenantProvider : ITenantProvider
    {
        private Guid _tenantId;

        public DatabaseTenantProvider(ApplicationDbContext context, IHttpContextAccessor accessor) 
        {
            var host = accessor.HttpContext.Request.Host.Value;

            context.AddSampleData();

            // This is for real life cases
            //_tenantId = context.Tenants.First(t => t.HostName == host).Id;

            _tenantId = context.Tenants.First(t => t.HostName == "imaginary.example.com").Id;
        }

        public Guid GetTenantId()
        {
            return _tenantId;
        }
    }
}
```

**/Data/ApplicationDbContext.cs:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using AthlosifyCore.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace AthlosifyCore.Data
{
    public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext
    {
        private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

        public DbSet<Tenant> Tenants { get; set; }
        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options,
                                    IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
            : base(options)
        {
            _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
        }
        public void AddSampleData()
        {
            Tenants.Add(new Tenant
            {
                Id = MultitenantDbContext.Tenant1Id,
                Name = "Imaginary corp.",
                HostName = "imaginary.example.com"
            });

            Tenants.Add(new Tenant
            {
                Id = MultitenantDbContext.Tenant2Id,
                Name = "The Very Big corp.",
                HostName = "big.example.com"
            });

            SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

**/Data/MultitenantDbContext.cs:**

```
using AthlosifyCore.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace AthlosifyCore.Data
{
    public class MultitenantDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public static Guid Tenant1Id = Guid.Parse("51aab199-1482-4f0d-8ff1-5ca0e7bc525a");
        public static Guid Tenant2Id = Guid.Parse("ae4e21fa-57cb-4733-b971-fdd14c4c667e");

        public DbSet<Person> People { get; set; }

        private ITenantProvider _tenantProvider;

        public MultitenantDbContext(DbContextOptions<MultitenantDbContext> options,
                                ITenantProvider tenantProvider) : base(options)
        {
            _tenantProvider = tenantProvider;
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Person>().HasQueryFilter(p => p.TenantId == _tenantProvider.GetTenantId());
        }

        public void AddSampleData()
        {
            People.Add(new Person
            {
                Id = Guid.Parse("79865406-e01b-422f-bd09-92e116a0664a"),
                TenantId = Tenant1Id,
                FirstName = "Gunnar",
                LastName = "Peipman"
            });

            People.Add(new Person
            {
                Id = Guid.Parse("d5674750-7f6b-43b9-b91b-d27b7ac13572"),
                TenantId = Tenant2Id,
                FirstName = "John",
                LastName = "Doe"
            });

            People.Add(new Person
            {
                Id = Guid.Parse("e41446f9-c779-4ff6-b3e5-752a3dad97bb"),
                TenantId = Tenant1Id,
                FirstName = "Mary",
                LastName = "Jones"
            });

            SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> we could NOT do the 2nd one for MultiTenantDbContext ... and it keeps saying issue on Object reference not set to an instance of an object which is related on `var host = accessor.HttpContext.Request.Host.Value; on /Models/Tenant.cs below.

That's because when you run dotnet-tool by `add-migration init` there's no `HttpContext` at all. In other words, the `accessor.HttpContext` is null at this time and then fails as you're accessing a `Request` property of `null`.

To fix that bug, change the code as below:

```
    public DatabaseTenantProvider(TenantsDbContext context, IHttpContextAccessor accessor)
    {
        var host = accessor.HttpContext?.Request.Host.Value;

        // ....
    }
```

Also, to avoid adding samples multiple times and causing an error of :

> ```
>  Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.Tenants'. The duplicate key value is (51aab199-1482-4f0d-8ff1-5ca0e7bc525a).
> ```

We should change the `AddSampleData()` method of `TenantsDbContext` class :

```
public class TenantsDbContext : DbContext
{
    // ....
    public void AddSampleData()
    {
        // add samples only if there's no record.
        if(Tenants.Count()==0){
            Tenants.Add(new Tenant
            {
                Id = MultitenantDbContext.Tenant1Id,
                Name = "Imaginary corp.",
                HostName = "imaginary.example.com"
            });
            Tenants.Add(new Tenant
            {
                Id = MultitenantDbContext.Tenant2Id,
                Name = "The Very Big corp.",
                HostName = "big.example.com"
            });
            SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

> Also my 2nd questions, I don't understand why this DatabaseTenantProvider class get executed in add-migration init on the MultiTenantDbContext ?!?!

That's because the `DatabaseTenantProvider` is registered as an implementation of `ITenantProvider` service,

```
services.AddTransient<ITenantProvider, DatabaseTenantProvider>()
```

which is required by the `MultitenantDbContext` class:

```
public class MultitenantDbContext : DbContext
{
    //...

    // note we inject the `ITenantProvider` service here!
    public MultitenantDbContext(DbContextOptions<MultitenantDbContext> options,
                                ITenantProvider tenantProvider) : base(options)
    {
        _tenantProvider = tenantProvider;
    }

}
```

When EF Core invokes the `MultitenantDbContext.OnModelCreating()` methods , it will then invoke the `ITenantProvider` service (i.e. the `DatabaseTenantProvider` class) to get the ID.